# I want to move whole mongo databse to linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

Now I am using windows, But I want to move on Ubuntu. I have Some mongo dbs in windows. How can I use them when I install linux on my pc?

Comment: This is not a programming-related question, so does not belong on StackOverflow. Similar questions could work on ServerFault or SuperUser, but in either case, you must explain an actual problem you're facing. Just asking for installation/migration instructions won't likely go over well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dump the database in windows
2. Copy the files to linux
3. Restore the database

See https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/